# How to add background color to whole row if 2 cells in that row have some specific background color in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to add some background color to the rows that have specific colors to two cells in it.

For example, the 4th row has y4 and z4 so if y4 has background color green and z4 has background color red, I would like to add the grey background to the whole 4th row. How can we achieve it?

I tried this based on values in these cells but it is not working `=AND(IF($Y1>$AB$6,1),IF($Z1>$AB$9,1))` so now trying based on the background color

please see the screenshot for your reference:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't (just like that) set conditional formatting based on color of another cell.

```
=AND(IF($Y1>$AB$6,1),IF($Z1>$AB$9,1))
```

[image]